# trying to connect strings in html

Tags: javascript

```html
<h2> Story Time </h2>
 <p> <b>
 Enter your favorite character:
  <input type="text" id="characterBox" size=40 value =""> <br> <br>
 Enter your favorite place:
  <input type="text" id="placeBox" size=40 value=""> <br> <br>
 Enter favorite food:
  <input type="text" id="foodBox" size=40 value=""> <br> <br>
 </p>
 <input type="button" value="click for story"
  onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
  'Once upon a time' 
  +document.getElementById('characterBox').value +
  'was flying through the sky when he hit a tree and fell to ground.
  To his surprise, he had landed in' 
  + document.getElementById('placeBox').value +
  '. He looked around and saw a Red Robin and realized he was hungry,
  so he went in and ordered a ' 
  + document.getElementById('foodBox').value +
  '. After eating, he was satisfied and found a park bench and went to 
  bed because it was too dark to fly back home.';">
 
 <hr>
 <div id="outputDiv"> </div>
```

this is my code and will not work. I am supposed to call upon a value from a text box to make a paragraph

Answer (score 0):

***1.*** You should close the `<b>` tag

***2.*** js string cut on new line. you should eather write it all in 1 line, or concat it using `+`, or use `` string (instead '' or "")

***3.*** you should add whitespace before and after inserted word

```html
<p> <b>
Enter your favorite character:
    <input type="text" id="characterBox" size=40 value =""> <br/> <br/>
Enter your favorite place:
    <input type="text" id="placeBox" size=40 value=""> <br/> <br/>
Enter favorite food:
    <input type="text" id="foodBox" size=40 value=""> <br/> <br/>
    </b>
</p>
<input type="button" value="click for story"
    onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
    'Once upon a time ' 
    +document.getElementById('characterBox').value +
    ' was flying through the sky when he hit a tree and fell to ground. To his surprise, he had landed in ' 
    + document.getElementById('placeBox').value +
    '. He looked around and saw a Red Robin and realized he was hungry, so he went in and ordered a ' 
    + document.getElementById('foodBox').value +
    '. After eating, he was satisfied and found a park bench and went to bed because it was too dark to fly back home.';">

<hr>
<div id="outputDiv"> </div>
```